# How to Search and Counting Whether the Set of Elements in List

Tags: python, loops

Below is the code that I search and count the *pos_xist* named list that holds the crawled element of en.wiktionary.org. The list holds the possible Part of Speech tag (with something not pos too) of wiktionary, and I search that list only to count how many of them in the list.
How can I shorten this code below in a more concise way?

```
count = 0
        for i in range(0,10): #assumed maximum count of possible POS is 10
            try:
                if 'Noun' in pos_xist[i]:
                    count +=1
                elif 'Verb' in pos_xist[i]:
                    count +=1
                elif 'Pronoun' in pos_xist[i]:
                    count +=1
                elif 'Adjective' in pos_xist[i]:
                    count +=1
                elif '' in pos_xist[i]:
                    count +=1
                elif 'Pronoun' in pos_xist[i]:
                    count +=1
                elif 'Adverb' in pos_xist[i]:
                    count +=1
                elif 'Particle' in pos_xist[i]:
                    count +=1
                elif 'Conjunction' in pos_xist[i]:
                    count +=1
                elif 'Interjection' in pos_xist[i]:
                    count +=1
                elif 'Prepoisition' in pos_xist[i]:
                    count +=1
                elif 'Determiner' in pos_xist[i]:
                    count +=1
                elif 'Article' in pos_xist[i]:
                    count +=1
                else:
                    pass
            except:
                pass
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a list of words to search for, and iterate over each item in `pos_xist` with a a generator expression:

```
words = ['Noun', 'Verb', 'Pronoun']
count = sum(any(word in item for word in words) for item in pos_xist)
```

If you want to limit to the first ten items use slicing `pos_xist[:10]`.

No exception handling should be necessary.

Comment: Wouldn't using a set improve complexity? i know the question doesn't ask that - just wondering :)

Comment: @PYA Making `words` a set? No because the `in` test is against `item` and iterating over lists and sets is similar in speed. Making `item` a set? Not as written, you'd have to build the set too many times

Answer (score 0):

```
postaglist=['Noun','Verb'...]
for item in pos_xist:
    if item in postaglist:
        count=count+1
```

form a list of all possible pos tags and search in them.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`any` builtin](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) coupled with just going through the list per item rather than waiting until an error is thrown.

It would look something like this

```
count = 0
words = ["Noun", "Verb", "Pronoun", ...]
for pos in pos_xist:
    if any(word in pos for word in words):
        count += 1
```

Comment: `count = sum(any(word in pos for word in words) for pos in pos_xist)`